# missing file attach error flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

I added firebase to my project in flutter, but the project does not open. I get this error "MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException (No implementation found for method Firebase # initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core))". Below are the sections I added for firebase. Can you help me?

I added to the pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^1.2.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.1.0
```

I also added them to the build.gradle in the app file:

```
      apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
      apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
      apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

This is also in the normal build.gradle:

```
  buildscript {
      ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
      repositories {
          google()
          jcenter ()
      }

      dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
          classpath 'com.google.gms: google-services: 4.3.6'
          classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin: kotlin-gradle-plugin: $ kotlin_version"
      }
   }

   allprojects {
       repositories {
           google()
           jcenter ()
       }
   }
```

This is main.dart:

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
 import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

 void main() async {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   await Firebase.initializeApp();
   runApp(MaterialApp(
     home: MyApp(),
     debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   ));
 }

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   // This widget is the root of your application.
   final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     CollectionReference customerref = firestore.collection('Customers');
     return Scaffold(
       backgroundColor: Colors.white,
       appBar: AppBar(
         title: Text('MyColorGame'),
         backgroundColor: Colors.black,
       ),
       body: Center(
         child: Container(
           child: Text(
             '${customerref.id}',
             style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
           ),
         ),
       ),
     );
   }
 }
```

I also put the json file in the app folder.
Where am I missing or wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Comment: I tried but the problem is still the same.